# How to implement leverage browser caching in nginx?

Tags: .htaccess, nginx, browser-cache

I have ho access to nginx.conf file (I see it but have no permission to edit it). Trying to add directive for mod_headers in .htaccess - no result. That is interesting, because mod_rewrite works fine through .htaccess

Comment: Nginx does not work with .htaccess. To use .htaccess, you must use apache.

Comment: I know. But I have nginx+apache on my server.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to the nginx config, for the location in question to add  or change any headers. Unless you can get access to config and reload config, you can't do it yourself.